# Why does it say I'm using more data than I am on my IPad?

Tags: ipad

[image]

It says that I have used 12.1 GB of data, but when added all up, it's no where near 12.1 GB. Maybe 10 GB at most, and I recently deleted a BUNCH of videos to clear up space, but it did nothing!

Answer (score -1):

I think it may be that it may be that your looking at the **iCloud storage** not the iPad storage (you probably haven't uploaded very much).